# Linux mmap() error

Tags: c, linux, memory, segmentation-fault, mmap

I have a memory mapped file, from which I wish to parse the contents of the buffer. The mmap() returns success, and I can print out the buffer contents to a file using fprintf successfully. However, when I try to access the buffer as an array in my program directly, I get a segmentation fault. Why is this happening? 
Here is the code:

```
  #define PTT_DUMP "/home/dhruv/somefile"     
  .
  .
  .

  int fd_ptt_dump = open(PTT_DUMP, O_RDONLY);
  struct stat struct_ptt_dump;
  fstat(fd_ptt_dump, &struct_ptt_dump);
  printf("\n\n\t\t\t --- The size of the dump is = %d -----\n\n",    struct_ptt_dump.st_size);
  char *membuffer;
  char pid_num[100];
  char cycles[100], instr[100], cpi[100] ;
  int pid_index =0;
  int cycles_index = 0;
  int instr_index = 0;
  int cpi_index = 0 ;
  int len = (int)struct_ptt_dump.st_size;
  int newline_count = 0;
  int n = 0;
  if( (membuffer = mmap(0, struct_ptt_dump.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, fd_ptt_dump, 0)) == (caddr_t) -1)
   err_sys("mmap error");

  /* If the following is uncommented, it prints fine */

  /*
  for ( n =0; n < struct_ptt_dump.st_size ; n++)      
  fprintf(fp_logfile,"%c", membuffer[n]);
  */

  /* But, I really want to access the buffer as an array for speed if possible */
  /* Here is where everything goes haywire */

  while (newline_count != 5)
   if ( membuffer[n++] == '\n' )
    newline_count++ ;

  /* printf returns OK, and I am able to skip newlines */

  printf("\n\n newlines = %d\n\n 10 buffer characters", newline_count);

  int k =0;


  /* All code from here gives segmentation fault */

  while ( membuffer[n++] != ' ' )
pid_num[pid_index++] = membuffer[n] ;

  /* Even if I comment out everything from here on, the above assignment itself results in a segmentation fault */


  pid_num[pid_index] = '\0';

  printf("\n\n pid = %s", pid_num);



  while ( membuffer[len--] != ' ' )
if ( membuffer[len] != '\n' )
  cpi[cpi_index++] = membuffer[len];

  cpi[cpi_index] = '\0';

  for( ; membuffer[len] == ' ' ; len-- )
;

  for(n=0; membuffer[len-n] != ' '; n++)
instr[instr_index++] = membuffer[len-n] ;

  instr[instr_index] = '\0' ;
  n++;

  for( ; membuffer[len-n] != ' ' ; n++)
cycles[cycles_index++] = membuffer[len-n];

  cycles[cycles_index] = '\0';

  printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t ********** buffer values *************\n\n");
  printf("\t\t\t\tdominant pid = %s\t cycles = %s\t instructions = %s\t cpi = %s \n\n", pid_num, cycles, instr, cpi);



  fflush(STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Comment: please run with gdb and specify the stack (where command in gdb).

Comment: Are there any restrictions on using the buffer directly? I could be messing up in the whiles and ifs and storing something more than I allocated for, but I was wondering if it is possible to access the memory directly in the first place or not. I know that accessing the buffer for the first time will raise a page fault but it should not really matter. As a side question, if some other process is scheduled due to a context switch right after the printf("\n\n newlines = %d .."), will the contents of buffer be restored when this process is again scheduled?

Comment: @Drakosha

Yes, I will do that and get back here with the stack info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How big is `pid_index` getting? Are you perhaps reading more than 100 characters without finding a space?

By the way, this

```
while ( membuffer[n++] != ' ' )
    pid_num[pid_index++] = membuffer[n] ;
```

should probably be this

```
while ( membuffer[n] != ' ' )
    pid_num[pid_index++] = membuffer[n++] ;
```

No?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The pid_index was indeed oveflowing. The program now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

- You aren't checking that n stays < struct_ptt_dump.st_size
- You aren't checking that pid_index stays < 100

Comment: Thanks, I put those bounds into the program for more robustness.